# Formatting a string to display hyperlinks and smilies

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my chat app, I'd like people to be able to post a URL and for it to be automatically hyperlinked by the app.  So for instance the message:

`Hi there! use http://google.com/ to search for things!`

Will get formatted to:

`Hi there! use <a href='http://google.com/'>http://google.com/</a> to search for things!`

Which isn't too hard, As far as I've found (from stackoverflow somewhere) is the following:

```
function addHyperlinks(str) {
    // Set the regex string
    var regex = /(https?:\/\/([-\w\-\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\-\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig
    // Replace plain text links by hyperlinks
    var replaced_text = str.replace(regex, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
    // Echo link
    return replaced_text;
}
```

This seems to work. But then I want to replace smilies with images too, so if the user posts:

`Hi there! use http://google.com/ to search for things! :D`

Will get formatted to:

`Hi there! use <a href='http://google.com/'>http://google.com/</a> to search for things! <img src='/grin.gif' />`

How can I do this? It seems like I need to be able to choose one or the other to make it work, as they both have colons in them, and the emoticon `:/` creates a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can replace emoticons by mapping one by one like this;

```
function replaceEmoticonToImageSrc(text) {
var siteUrl = 'http://www.yoursite.com/'
var emoticons = {
    ':D'  : 'emoticongif.gif',
    ':)'  : 'emoticon2gif.gif',
  };
  return text.replace(/[:\-)D]+/g, function (match) {
    return typeof emoticons[match] != 'undefined' ?
           '<img src="' + siteUrl + emoticons[match] + '"/>' :
           match;
  });
}
```